# Exchange/Outlook 2003 Operation Failed

Tags: exchange, outlook, attachment

I am having problems across an entire site running Exchange 2003 SP2 on Server 2003 SP2, and not entirely patched up to date.  The site has been running fine for 12+ months, and suddenly there are problems everywhere.

The clients are running Outlook 2003 SP3.  Word is set as the email editor.  When sending any attachment (including embedded images in their sigs), they receive an 'The operation failed" message.  Nothing appears in the logs.

I have tried setting up new users and they have the same problem.
I have tried cleaning the Office install and installing again.
Using OWA, I can send an attachment.

If I disable using Word as the editor, I still get "The operation failed" when attaching a file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the Store is corrupted. Follow [petri.co.il](http://www.petri.co.il/check_exchange_2000_2003_server_databases_integrity.htm) to get do checks on the store and if needed, it will also tell you how to repair it.

Comment: Running the checks now.  The .edb was fine, but there are a lot of checksum errors on the .stm.

Comment: Hrmm, "Operation terminated with error -1018".  I think it's restore from backup time.